# Consulta en mysql para obtener un reporte de asistencia

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con una plataforma y quiero obtener un reporte personalizado, que lleve los siguientes campos.

- EmployeeID
- CodeID
- DepartmentName
- Name
- Turno
- Horario
- Entrada
- Salida
- CurrentDay
- Time1

Para este ejemplo me basaré en el empleado con **id 101104** que esta en turno **Oficina B** el cual tiene **4 horarios (Mat Oficina Mixto,Matutino Sucursales,Descanso, Sábado A)**

Las tablas que estoy utilizando son:

**personnel_employee** - Datos del empleado
[image: personnel_employee]

**att_attshift** - Datos del turnos
[image: att_attshift]

**att_shiftdetail** - Aquí se relacionan los turnos con los horarios
[image: att_shiftdetail]

**att_timeinterval** - Datos de los horarios (solo adjunto los que son necesarios para el ejemplo) esa tabla no incluye un campo con la hora de salida, solo tiene un campo llamado duración en el cual se guardan los minutos, es por eso que tuve que hacer un cálculo para poder convertir los minutos en horas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**att_attschedule** - Calendarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**personnel_department** - Datos del departamento

[image: personnel_department]

**iclock_transaction** - Datos de las checadas
[image: iclock_transaction]

Intentamos con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT personnel_employee.id AS 'EmployeeID', personnel_employee.emp_code AS 'CodeID', dept_name AS 'DepartmentName',
personnel_employee.first_name AS 'Name', att_attshift.alias AS 'Schedule', att_timeinterval.alias as 'horario',
CAST(att_timeinterval.in_time AS datetime) AS 'FixedEntrance',
CAST(addtime((floor(duration/60)*10000 + (duration%60*100)), time(att_timeinterval.in_time)) AS datetime) AS 'FixedExit',
CAST(iclock_transaction.punch_time AS date) AS 'CurrentDay',
DATE_FORMAT(iclock_transaction.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Time1'
FROM att_shiftdetail
INNER JOIN att_attshift ON att_attshift.id = att_shiftdetail.shift_id
INNER JOIN att_timeinterval ON att_timeinterval.id = att_shiftdetail.time_interval_id
INNER JOIN att_attschedule ON att_attschedule.shift_id = att_attshift.id
INNER JOIN personnel_employee ON att_attschedule.employee_id = personnel_employee.id
INNER JOIN iclock_transaction ON personnel_employee.emp_code = iclock_transaction.emp_code
INNER JOIN personnel_department ON personnel_employee.department_id = personnel_department.id
WHERE personnel_employee.status <> 3 AND CAST(iclock_transaction.punch_time AS date)
BETWEEN '2018-05-11' AND '2018-05-28' AND personnel_department.id = '11' AND personnel_employee.emp_code = '101104'
and dayname(iclock_transaction.punch_time)=elt(att_shiftdetail.day_index mod 7 + 1, 'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
and elt(att_shiftdetail.day_index mod 7 + 1, '0','1','2','3','4','5','6')=att_shiftdetail.day_index
group by iclock_transaction.punch_time
ORDER BY personnel_employee.emp_code,iclock_transaction.punch_time;
```

Pero tenemos un detalle, ya que si observan la tabla **att_attshift - Datos del turnos** tiene como cycle_unit **1** que significa que es **semana** y en shift_cycle tiene **2** o sea que son dos semanas, ahora en **att_shiftdetail** vemos que hay un campo llamado **day_index** que va desde el 0 al 13 en donde

0 Domingo
1 Lunes
2 Martes
3 Miércoles
4 Jueves
5 Viernes
6 Sábado
7 Domingo
8 Lunes
9 Martes
10 Miércoles
11 Jueves
12 Viernes
13 Sábado

Lo que significa que cada semana maneja horarios diferentes en cada día, en la plataforma lo visualizo de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de la consulta que hicimos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sábado 11-05-2018 es la segunda semana de mayo por lo cual debería de tener el horario Matutino Sucursales y el 28-05-2018  debería ser el horario Mat Oficina Mixto ya que se volvería a repetir el ciclo considerando esta como la semana 1.

¿Cómo puedo relacionar el horario(nombre,entrada y salida) de acuerdo a la semana y el día CurrentDay?

Resultados de la consulta propuesta:
Al ejecutar la consulta me arroja los siguientes datos
[image: resultados]

Pero el nombre de horario no coincide con el rango de tiempo de dicho horario, siguiendo el ejemplo vemos que la fecha es en mayo, ahora si volvemos al resultado de la consulta vemos que los días 11,12,22,23,25,26 corresponden a la semana 2, el horario es Matutino Sucursales eso esta bien pero el FixedEntrance y FixedExit no concuerdan con el rango de tiempo que le corresponde a ese horario,ya que debería ser de 8:50-16:50 y en el resultado de la consulta dice 8:50-19:20

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado y que me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: te recomendaria que vieras [mcve] ya que me parece que es dificil entender que estas buscando exactamente. Ojo, no esta mal explicado, solo que se hace extenso y confuso

Comment: Tal como te sugiere @gbianchi, te recomiendo que proporciones un ejemplo con datos simulados así como el resultado que se debe obtener... intentar decirte qué falla en esa pedazo de consulta enorme solo mirando imágenes hace que sea imposible seguir el curso!

Comment: Creo que en realidad tu `FixedEntrance` y `FixedExit` debería ser [`CurrentDay` concatenado con la hora(`in_time`) ], ya que in_time sólo te da la hora de ingreso y salida.

Comment: Podrías intentar esto? https://pastebin.com/hCRhHkgQ Es tu misma consulta (con buen formato), simplemente cambié una cosa, el horario lo puse como una búsqueda dinámica (subquery), ya que esa columna depende de la semana en la que están actualmente en el mes.

Comment: Hola @L.Flor estoy checando lo que me dices, pero justo en el if me marca un error de sintaxis :(

Comment: Perdona, sólo faltaba encerrar los select internos entre paréntesis, aquí lo tienes sin errores https://pastebin.com/AeyC7Wee

Comment: Faltó un criterio de comparación en los selects internos que hice, si lo notas sólo puse `SELECT time_interval_id FROM att_shiftdetail ats2 WHERE ats2.day_index=...` Pero faltaría agregarle el id del `sift_id = 12`

Comment: Si no sabes de lo que estoy hablando, aquí lo agregué https://pastebin.com/61CqyfzJ, en realidad debería ir el id del join pero como es un ejemplo directo para ese `employee` puedes ponerle directamente `12`

Comment: Hola @L.Flor acabo de agregar los resultados de tu propuesta, pero tengo unos detalles :c ya edite mi pregunta y puse el detalle que tengo

Comment: Una pregunta, qué distintos valores puede tomar shift_cycle?

Comment: Básicamente es repetir la búsqueda para hallar la hora de entrada y salida: https://pastebin.com/wkhjTQwx

Comment: shift_cycle depende del número de semanas que se le agregue al turno, en este ejemplo su valor es 2 ya que tiene dos semanas con distintos horarios, pero existen otros turnos donde shif_cycle vale 1 ya que solo cuentan con una semana con un horario en toda la semana

Comment: Hola @L.Flor ya me funciona bien con el id_shift en específico, pero ahora quiero hacerlo para todas mis consultas, me mencionabas algo del **id join**  ¿A qué te refieres? es que intente poner `WHERE ats.shift_id = att_attshift.id` en los selects internos, pero no funciona como debe ser :/

Comment: El análisis que hice sólo fue en base al ejemplo que pusiste (Es decir, sólo funcionará para aquellos que tengan shift_cycle=2 [0,13]), no tengo el panorama completo, pero dado que el ciclo es cambiante, el cálculo deberá cambiar, ahora para mí es imposible saber cómo analizar los otros casos porque los desconozco.

Comment: @L.Flor podrías poner tu respuesta en la sección de preguntas para marcarla como solución, gracias

Comment: Hola @L.Flor disculpa me quede con una duda, en tu cuarto comentario mencionas que en lugar del 12 debería ir el id del join ¿a que te refieres? lo que pasa es que ya le quiero quitar el 12 estático y me hace mucho énfasis lo que dices, lo del id del join

Comment: No me había percatado de que no haces join con la tabla `att_shiftdetail` sino que haces un `FROM` desde allí, te recomiendo ponerle un alias de esta manera `...FROM att_shiftdetail alias_cualquiera` y reemplazar el número 12 por `... = alias_cualquiera.shift_id` o si no le pones el alias, simplemente ponerle el nombre de la tabla, pero el uso de alias simplifica las cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el ejemplo que pusiste, según el análisis que hice, el único problema era saber si el día en que había marcado asistencia estaba dentro de una semana par o impar en ese mes.

- Si era **par**: Implicaba que el día pertenecía al segundo grupo de horario [7 - 13].
- Si era **impar**: Implicaba que el día pertenecía al primer grupo de horario [0 - 6].

Una vez encontrado a qué grupo pertenecía simplemente tenías que sumarle el índice del día.

Por ejemplo:

- Para el día `11-05-2018`

  Pertenece a la `segunda` (**par**) semana del mes de mayo, por ende tomaremos del [7 al 13]. Luego, le sumamos el índice del día para obtener el registro final.

  El día 11 cae `viernes` por lo que su índice es `5` (contando desde el domingo 0)
  Entonces, el día horario (`day_index`), en la tabla **att_shiftdetail**, que le corresponde sería

  ```
  [ 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 ]

   7 + 5 =>               ^^
  ```

Entonces, sabemos que el índice de horario para esa fecha es `12`, con ese dato nos vamos a la tabla **att_shiftdetail** y buscamos su rango de horas y también el **time_interval_id** que es importante para conocer el alias del horario.

---

Entonces, pasando a construir el **query**:

Primero verificamos si la semana es par o impar, usando [WEEK()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php), al cual le pasamos el modo 2 para que entienda que la semana empieza los domingos:

```
SELECT (WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time, 2) - 
        WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time - INTERVAL DAY(iclock_transaction.punch_time)-1 DAY, 2)
```

- `WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time, 2)`: Retornará la semana del año de esa fecha.
- `WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time - INTERVAL DAY(iclock_transaction.punch_time)-1 DAY, 2)`: Retornará la semana del año de esa fecha pero desde el primer día de ese mes.

Puedes ver más al respecto en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553434/6459968) sobre cómo hallar el número de semana en un mes específico.

Una vez obtenido el número de semana en el mes, para hallar si es múltiplo de 2 o no, simplemente utilizamos el operador `%`.

**La lógica iría quedando así:**

```
SELECT IF(numero_semana % 2 = 0, "Es par", "Es impar")
```

- **Si es par:** Básicamente si es par sabemos que su grupo será de [7 a 13] por lo dicho al inicio, utilizando [DAYOFWEEK()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php):

  ```
  day_index = (7 + DAYOFWEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time) - 1)
  ```
- **Si es impar:** Si es impar sabemos que su grupo será de [0 a 6] por lo dicho al inicio, utilizando [DAYOFWEEK()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php):

  ```
  day_index = (0 + DAYOFWEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time) - 1)
  ```

**Finalmente, la búsqueda queda de la siguiente manera:**

```
IF((WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time, 2) - WEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time - INTERVAL DAY(iclock_transaction.punch_time)-1 DAY, 2) + 1) % 2 = 0,
        (SELECT att1.alias FROM att_timeinterval att1 WHERE att1.id = (SELECT time_interval_id FROM att_shiftdetail ats WHERE ats.shift_id = 12 AND ats.day_index = (7 + DAYOFWEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time) - 1) LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1),
        (SELECT att2.alias FROM att_timeinterval att2 WHERE att2.id = (SELECT time_interval_id FROM att_shiftdetail ats2 WHERE ats2.shift_id = 12 AND ats2.day_index = (0 + DAYOFWEEK(iclock_transaction.punch_time) - 1) LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1)) AS horario
```

Dicho procedimiento de búsqueda se debe repetir para obtener el alias y rango de horarios.